# How to write modules on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, module

I'm currently writing a program that should be working on both Windows and Linux. The program uses dynamic modules (LoadLibrary/dlopen) to simplify deployment of different functions.

The Linux part works just fine: The main program exports functions and variables with -Wl,--export-dynamic so the modules can access them, and the modules can be compiled with gcc's -shared option without the requirement to resolve all symbol dependencies when linking.

With Windows (using MSVC 2010), this seems not to work. I'm exporting functions and variables from the main program using __declspec(dllimport), but I am not able to access functions and variables from the main program because linking fails (unresolved external, LNK1120).

How to deal with this? Thank you.

**Edit (code sample):**

*core-file.cpp*

```
#include "core-file.hpp"

Cls_A cls_instance;

void Cls_A::do_something() {
    while(0);
}
```

*core-file.hpp*

```
#ifdef TEST_EXPORTS
#define TEST_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TEST_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class TEST_API Cls_A {
public:
    void do_something();
};

extern Cls_A cls_instance;
```

*module.cpp*

```
#include "core-file.hpp"

TEST_API int my_init_function() {
    cls_instance.do_something();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that exhibits the problem.  Some of your statements don't make much sense (e.g. "I'm exporting functions...using `__declspec(dllimport)`;" do you mean `dllexport`? do you mean that you are importing functions?).

Comment: A DLL has a LibMain. Did you set the proper configuration type in your VS 2010 project's configuration properties?

Comment: Why on earth would you use MSVC on Windows when you're already using GCC on Linux? Go for GCC on all platforms, that's going to make your work a lot easier and less problematic.

Answer (score 2):

`__declspec(dllimport)` is for when you're compiling the the program that *uses* the DLL. When you compiling the actual DLL, you want to use `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Your use of these must be consistent. The typical idiom is to define a macro that will use dllimport and dllexport based on the presence of a macro. In the project the builds the DLL, you define the macro that means to export the functions, and in other projects you don't define it, which means to import them:

```
#ifdef PROJECT_NAME_BUILD_DLL
  #define DLL_SYMBOL __declspec(dllexport)
#else //PROJECT_NAME_BUILD_DLL
  #define DLL_SYMBOL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif //PROJECT_NAME_BUILD_DLL

DLL_SYMBOL void SomeFunction(Type value);
```

The project that builds the DLL will define `PROJECT_NAME_BUILD_DLL`; projects that *use* the DLL which include this header do not define this.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, when you want to link against exported symbols you have to remember to specify all the import libraries that were generated when you linked the modules whose symbols you want to import. (You can just leave the symbols unresolved on Linux because the executable format is different and it's possible to defer symbol resolution to load time.)

Comment: That's something I remember - so even with gcc on Windows this wouldn't be possible. Thank you.